# Binding 'GO' key on Software Keyboard

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I've got a log-in button bound to a command that exists inside my `ViewModel` like so:

```
this.AddBindings(new Dictionary<object, string>{{btnLogin,"TouchUpInside LoginCommand"}});
```

The software keyboard is suppressed if a touch is made, somewhere outside the keyboard or `UITextField`.
To prevent the user from having to click once somewhere on the screen to make the keyboard disappear and then pressing the log-in button, I would like to associate the log-in command defined in the `ViewModel` to the 'GO' key in the keyboard. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple solution is the one given in the previous answer.

However, if you wanted to go further, then you could add a custom binding, implemented something like:

```
public class MvxUITextFieldShouldReturnTargetBinding
    : MvxTargetBinding
{
    private ICommand _command;

    protected UITextField View
    {
        get { return Target as UITextField; }
    }

    public MvxUITextFieldShouldReturnTargetBinding(UITextField target)
        : base(target)
    {
        target.ShouldReturn = HandleShouldReturn;
    }

    private bool HandleShouldReturn(UITextField textField)
    {
        if (_command == null)
            return false;

        var text = textField.Text;
        if (!_command.CanExecute(text))
            return false;

        textField.ResignFirstResponder();
        _command.Execute(text);
        return true;
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
    {
        get { return MvxBindingMode.OneWay; }
    }

    public override void SetValue(object value)
    {
        var command = value as ICommand;
        _command = command;
    }

    public override System.Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof(ICommand); }
    }


    protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(isDisposing);
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            var editText = View;
            if (editText != null)
            {
                editText.ShouldReturn = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which you could register during setup as:

```
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<UITextField>("ShouldReturn",
                                                           textField => new MvxUITextFieldShouldReturnTargetBinding(textField));
```

I think that would work - it should allow you to bind a `MvxCommand` or an `MvxCommand<string>`

For more on custom bindings, see N=28 in http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com

Comment: What is the advantage of making a custom binding instead of a delegate in this case?

Answer (score 5):

You can't bind the button itself. This is dependent on the focused `UIView` which triggers the keyboard to have the `GO` button. I.e. if it is a `UITextField` you can assign a function or delegate to the `ShouldReturn` property, which then triggers your `LoginCommand`. Something like:

```
myUiTextField.ShouldReturn += delegate
    {
        ViewModel.LoginCommand.Execute(null);
        return true;
    };
```

Read more about the property in the [Xamarin.iOS API documentation](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField/P).

Comment: Small note, the return of a boolean is expected:

myUiTextField.ShouldReturn += (textField) => { 
                CurrentViewModel.LoginCommand.Execute(null);
                return true; 
            };