# MvvmCross UITextField custom binding

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

So I am trying to implement a custom binding for a UITextField in MvvmCross, pretty much along the lines of [Binding 'GO' key on Software Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452163/binding-go-key-on-software-keyboard) - i.e. trying to bind a text field to automatically fire an event when the Done button is tapped on the keyboard (so binding to `ShouldReturn`). I also need to bind the text field's `EditingDidBegin` and `EditingDidEnd` events. Because I am binding more than one event, I have created a `MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding` as follows:

```
public class MyTextFieldTargetBinding : MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding<UITextField>
{
    private ICommand _command;

    protected UITextField TextField
    {
        get { return (UITextField)Target; }
    }

    public MyTextFieldTargetBinding(object target, PropertyInfo targetPropertyInfo) : base(target, targetPropertyInfo)
    {
        TextField.ShouldReturn += HandleShouldReturn;
        TextField.EditingDidBegin += HandleEditingDidBegin;
        TextField.EditingDidEnd += HandleEditingDidEnd;
    }

    private bool HandleShouldReturn(UITextField textField)
    {
        if (_command == null) {
            return false;
        }

        var text = textField.Text;
        if (!_command.CanExecute (text)) {
            return false;
        }

        textField.ResignFirstResponder();
        _command.Execute(text);

        return true;
    }

    private void HandleEditingDidBegin (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do something
    }

    private void HandleEditingDidEnd (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do something
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
    {
        get { return MvxBindingMode.OneWay; }
    }

    public override void SetValue(object value)
    {
        var command = value as ICommand;
        _command = command;
    }

    public override Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof(ICommand); }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            if (TextField != null)
            {
                TextField.ShouldReturn -= HandleShouldReturn;
                TextField.EditingDidBegin -= HandleEditingDidBegin;
                TextField.EditingDidEnd -= HandleEditingDidEnd;
            }
        }

        base.Dispose(isDisposing);
    }
```

}

My first question is: am I correct in creating one `MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding` for all the events? Relatedly, I don't get the difference between `MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding` and  `MvxTargetBinding`. According to [MVVMCross Binding decimal to UITextField removes decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603755/mvvmcross-binding-decimal-to-uitextfield-removes-decimal-point) the former is used when replacing an existing binding, the latter for known properties and event pairs. So am I using the correct one?

Secondly (and the real crux of my problem), my code works **except for** `SetValue` - it is fired, but the `value` is `null`. Here is what I have in my `Setup` file:

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories (IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
{
    base.FillTargetFactories (registry);
    registry.RegisterPropertyInfoBindingFactory(typeof(MyTextFieldTargetBinding), typeof(UITextField), "Text");
}
```

I don't do anything in my `View` - perhaps that is where the issue lies?

**EDIT:**

My `ViewModel`:

```
public class LoginViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private string _username;
    public string Username
    { 
        get { return _username; }
        set { _username = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Username); }
    }

    private string _password;
    public string Password
    { 
        get { return _password; }
        set { _password = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Password); }
    }

    private MvxCommand _login;
    public ICommand Login
    {
        get {
            _login = _login ?? new MvxCommand(DoLogin);
            return _login;
        }
    }

    public LoginViewModel(ILoginManager loginManager)
    {
        _loginManager = loginManager;
    }

    private void DoLogin()
    {
        // call the login web service
    }
}
```

In my `View', I don't do anything fancy (I do create the View elements in a XIB):

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    this.NavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden(true, false);

    var set = this.CreateBindingSet<LoginView, Core.ViewModels.LoginViewModel>();
    set.Bind(usernameTextField).To(vm => vm.Username);
    set.Bind(passwordTextField).To(vm => vm.Password);
    set.Bind (loginButton).To (vm => vm.Login);
    set.Apply();
}
```

No interesting Trace messages.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include: the binding code, the view model property you are binding to, and any relevant or worrisome trace you are seeing during binding?

Comment: Done. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: Argh - just wrote looking answer and my phone ate it :/ back later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. What is special about PropertyInfoTargetBinding?

The question you reference - [MVVMCross Binding decimal to UITextField removes decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603755/mvvmcross-binding-decimal-to-uitextfield-removes-decimal-point) - gives the key to the difference between `MvxTargetBinding` and `MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding`:

- TargetBinding can be used for any arbitrary binding - e.g. for `a non-propertyInfo-based binding`
- PropertyInfoTargetBinding inherits from TargetBinding and can only be used with actual C# Properties - because it uses PropertyInfo via Reflection.

In your case, since you aren't actually using the `Text` property via Reflection, then I'd be tempted **not** to use a PropertyInfoTargetBinding and to steer clear of the `Text` name as well - instead just write a custom TargetBinding.

> the former is used when replacing an existing binding

This is definitely not true - instead any binding can be used to replace another binding - as the answer on the other question says

> MvvmCross operates a simple 'last registered wins' system

For more on custom bindings, take a look at:

- the N=28 video in http://mvvmcross.blogspot.co.uk/
- take a look through some of the "standard" bindings that ship with MvvmCross

  - Droid - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Target
  - iOS - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Target
  - note that most of these use either MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding or MvxConvertingTargetBinding as a base class

---

#### 2. Why is my SetValue getting null?

Your current binding code is asking for an ICommand:

```
public override Type TargetType
{
    get { return typeof(ICommand); }
}
```

But your View code is currently binding the View to a `string`:

```
// View
set.Bind(usernameTextField).To(vm => vm.Username);

// ViewModel
private string _username;
public string Username
{ 
    get { return _username; }
    set { _username = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Username); }
}
```

To solve this...

1. Work out what you want to bind to - is it an ICommand (e.g. and MvxCommand) or is it a `string`?
2. Change the View and the Binding to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks. I solved the issue by using `MvxTargetBinding` (basically using the implementation used in [Binding 'GO' key on Software Keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452163/binding-go-key-on-software-keyboard)), and changing my binding code in my `View` to:
    `set.Bind(usernameTextField).To(vm => vm.Username);
    set.Bind(passwordTextField).To(vm => vm.Password);  
    set.Bind(passwordTextField).For("ShouldReturn").To(vm => vm.Login);`
(I didn't know you could bind a field twice!)